# Directed or bi-directed and MSSP

Tags: tree, graph-algorithm, shortest-path

Firstly i wanted to ask. If I have a undirected graph and split all the edges into two directed edges is it still called directed or it becomes bi-directed?

[image: this is a picture of what i wanted to mean]

The main question is i have a graph with n sources all in the same graph until now i thought i could use the mssp method provided by Klein in this [paper](http://planarity.org/Klein_multiple_source_shortest_paths.pdf) but it says that the graph must be a directed graph. yet if i have an undirected graph and split each edges into two components with same weight i don't think it will be able to solve the problem or it does not matter?

due the bidirection of the graph, will it have the first source visit each and every node without the other sources, implyinging that i cant adapt the graph such that i can have a Shortest path tree as if i ran a dijkstra ion the other sources does it?

also i wanted to make sure does this method gets all the shortest path trees? because i was getting confused.

Comment: why not use dijkstra? is your graph fullfilling the other requirements mentioned in the paper?

Comment: yes it does. If i use dijkstra i would have a running time complexity of O(n^3) whilst by MSSP i ca have a running time of O(n^2+ nlogn)

Comment: Without reading the paper in detail my intuition says that you aren't allowed to 'cheat' :) ... I would try with dijkstra and only if that is too slow move to this algorithm. E.g. if you already have an undirected graph then the direction does not matter and you save half of the m*n calculations. BTW: very interesting question. I'll probalby read the paper later on

Comment: Cross-posted:  http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/17538